# Best way to improve (fuzzy) search results for similarities?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, levenshtein-distance, fuzzy-search

> This question may like a duplicate question but I’m giving it back because I couldn’t perfect a solution.

Sorry for that.
Now I'm working on a drug search engine. The user cannot always enter the exact drug name. Depending on the characters entered by the user, I need to get a better result for them. But now it is not. How should I do to do result more accurately? For example, there is information in DB: `Анальгин, Цитрамон-П, Лирика-75мг`, etc. ... (in *Cyrillic*). If the user enters in the Latin alphabet, the system converts it to the Cyrillic alphabet and searches through it. So, I need that: Even if the user enters words in `Цитрамон, cитрамон, ииттрамон or cтрамон`, the result should return *Цитрамон*. Or if user enter: `Лирика, ЛЛЛирика, иииррика, Лика or Лирик`, the result should return *Лирика*. Or `Аналгин, Анагин ...` should returns *Анальгин*.
I should get similar results. I tried several search algorithms and packages (Laravel-Searchy, Laravel Scout, TNTSearch and etc) but to no avail. Now a search is working but the results are returning the same as in a SQL LIKE operator. Also, I tried with Levenstein distance as follow as:
My search variable:

```
 $data = [];
 //dd($request->all());
 $search = _ltc($request->qry); // convert input text between latin and crylic 
  $data = Drug::selectRaw('*, levenshtein(?, `name`) as `diff`', [$search])
                ->havingBetween('diff', [0,4])
                ->limit(10)
                ->get();
```

And my SQL levenshtein function:

```
CREATE DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost'
  FUNCTION arzondori.levenshtein(s1 VARCHAR(255), s2 VARCHAR(255) )
  RETURNS INT(11)
 DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN 
DECLARE s1_len, s2_len, i, j, c, c_temp, cost INT; 
DECLARE s1_char CHAR; 
-- max strlen=255 
DECLARE cv0, cv1 VARBINARY(256); 
SET s1_len = CHAR_LENGTH(s1), s2_len = CHAR_LENGTH(s2), cv1 = 0x00, j = 1, i = 1, c = 0; 
IF s1 = s2 THEN 
 RETURN 0; 
 ELSEIF s1_len = 0 THEN 
 RETURN s2_len; 
 ELSEIF s2_len = 0 THEN 
 RETURN s1_len; 
ELSE 
WHILE j <= s2_len DO 
 SET cv1 = CONCAT(cv1, UNHEX(HEX(j))), j = j + 1; 
END WHILE; 
WHILE i <= s1_len DO 
 SET s1_char = SUBSTRING(s1, i, 1), c = i, cv0 = UNHEX(HEX(i)), j = 1; 
WHILE j <= s2_len DO 
  SET c = c + 1; 
  IF s1_char = SUBSTRING(s2, j, 1) THEN  
    SET cost = 0; ELSE SET cost = 1; 
  END IF; 
  SET c_temp = CONV(HEX(SUBSTRING(cv1, j, 1)), 16, 10) + cost; 
  IF c > c_temp THEN SET c = c_temp; END IF; 
    SET c_temp = CONV(HEX(SUBSTRING(cv1, j+1, 1)), 16, 10) + 1; 
    IF c > c_temp THEN  
      SET c = c_temp;  
    END IF; 
   SET cv0 = CONCAT(cv0, UNHEX(HEX(c))), j = j + 1; 
  END WHILE; 
      SET cv1 = cv0, i = i + 1; 
     END WHILE; 
    END IF; 
   RETURN c; 
  END
```

I also considered the following options.:

```
$data = Drug::select("id", "name")
                ->where('name', 'LIKE', "%$search%")
                ->get();
 $data5 = Searchy::search('drugs')
                   ->fields('name')
                   ->query($search)
                   ->select('id', 'name')
                   ->get();
```

Can anyone help find a solution to this problem? Sorry in advance if the question is a little confusing!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be very hard to solve in the way you are trying. You need a full text search engine like Sphinx or elastic search. That has support for languages and fuzzy search. More info about it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full-text_search

I recommend Sphinx:
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/sphinx3.html#features-overview

The documentation is however very heavy. Another option is elasticsearch that has very good documentation.

Try to invent this your self will be very tricky and you will take time to get good result.

Comment: Ok thanks bro! I will try the ways you said. The first way was a little satisfying. Also, can you suggest any good lib for Elasticsearch? Closer to the problem I have?

Answer (score 1):

I know you've already accepted another answer, and a full text search tool like Sphinx or Elasticsearch is a strong option, but there is another one that may be simpler for your use case.

You don't mention what database you're using, but many of them have at least some support for full text search. For instance, in MariaDB and MySQL you can search against a FULLTEXT index. First you'd need to create the index:

```
ALTER TABLE drugs ADD FULLTEXT (name);
```

Then, you can replace the LIKE clause in your query with a MATCH clause against the indexed column, as in this example:

```
Drug::whereRaw('MATCH(name) AGAINST (?)', [$search]);
```

There's a lot of options for full text search, so if you want to extend it to allow more or less ambiguity in results, or order the results by the quality of the match, that's possible, but without knowing what database you're using I can't really elaborate,  so I'd suggest looking at the docs for your database. Matching against a full text index not only allows for more ambiguity than a LIKE clause, but it's also more performant. If your use case is simple enough that you don't need a separate search backend (and it sounds like that's the case), then your database's full text search capability may be sufficient, and it's likely to be quicker and easier than integrating Elasticsearch.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using MySQL 5.7. I tried the Full Text search but it went from letter to letter search. That is, if I type `google`, it produces other results starting with `g`, but it is available in db `google` word. Draws results on non-existent letters.

Comment: MySQL 5.7 should be able to do what you want, but the query might need tweaking. The docs at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-natural-language.html should get you started. You should be able to order it by the score with something like `ORDER BY MATCH(name) DESC`, and Eloquent has an `orderByRaw()` method to pass it through.

Comment: Ok bro! I tried all of them, also i tried with your `Drug::whereRaw('MATCH(name) AGAINST (?)', [$search]);` example, and it doesn't return anything. Full text search, searches only similer words, like if i enter google it found but if i enter goo it doesn't match anything.

Comment: Don't know if this'll help anybody but the full text search returning nothing problem sounds like something I've seen - I created a full text search on several fields like "name, description, address" - full text search always returned nothing unless my query specified all columns by name and in the same order as when the full text index was created. I believe it was related to the version of mysql I had but I'm not an expert - just hope that this sparks something and helps somebody out.